# Obtain the first element from an array variable that is passed by reference

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, c-strings

i am having trouble to obtain the individual element information from referencing an array and pointer. 
Also, i cant rewrite the pointer value and pass it back to the main reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void strings(char word[][40], char *first, char *last, int size);

int main()
{
 char word[10][40];
 char first[40], last[40];
 int i, size;

 printf("Enter size: \n");
 scanf("%d", &size); //storing size
 printf("Enter %d words: \n", size);
 for (i=0; i<size; i++)
 scanf("%s", word[i]); //storing user input
 deriving(word, first, last, size);
 printf("First word = %s, Last word = %s\n", first, last);
 return 0;
}
void deriving(char word[][40], char *first, char *last, int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    char *ptr = word; //why is it when i store the user input as a  ptr variable i am able to get each element?
    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        printf("number of lines = number of elements \n");
        ptr++;
    }

    while(*(word+count) != '\0')
    {
        count ++;
        printf(" element is present");  // it is stuck in a infinite loop here. 
    }

    first = "first word"; //why does this two commands not carry into the main function? since i am rewriting the whole pointer
    last = "last word";

}
```

Comment: Remember that arguments in C are passed *by value*. That means the value is *copied* into the argument variables. Modifying a copy (like assigning to an argument variable) will only modify the copy, not the original. You might want to either read about *emulating pass by reference in C*, or pass pointers to the first elements of arrays, which you then `strcpy` to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this declaration

```
char *ptr = word;
```

is invalid. The initializer has the type  char ( * )[40] according to the declarauin of the parameter `word` like

```
char word[][40]
```

And there is no implicit conversion from one pointer type to another.

So you have to write

```
char ( *ptr ) = word;
```

As a result these loops

```
while(*ptr != '\0')
{
    printf("number of lines = number of elements \n");
    ptr++;
}

while(*(word+count) != '\0')
{
    count ++;
    printf(" element is present");  // it is stuck in a infinite loop here. 
}
```

are incorrect also because the array word was not initialized.

```
char word[10][40];
```

Take into account that as the variable `word` has the type `char ( * )[40]`  then dereferencing the expression `*(word+count)` you get an object of the type `char[40]`. There is no sense to compare it with the value `'\0'` because this comparison is equivalent to

```
*(word+count) != NULL
```

As the left operand is not a null pointer then the condition evaluates to true.

As for `first` and `last`  then they are local variables of the function that have copies of the values of the passed arguments that is they contain addresses of first characters of the arrays used as function arguments. So changing the local variables does not influence on the original arrays.

Moreover you may not reassign an array because arrays are non-modifiable lvalues.

You have to copy string literals to the elements of the arrays.

For example

```
strcpy(first, "first word" ); 
strcpy( last, "last word" );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   40

void f( char *first, char *last )
{
    strcpy( first, "first word" ); 
    strcpy( last, "last word" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char first[N], last[N];

    f( first, last );

    printf( "First word = %s, Last word = %s\n", first, last );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
First word = first word, Last word = last word
enter code here
```

And another demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define M   10
#define N   40

void f( char word[][N], size_t n )
{
    size_t count = 0;
    char ( *p )[N] = word;

    while ( count < n && **( p + count ) != '\0' ) ++count;

    printf( "There are %zu non-empty strings\n", count );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char word[M][N] =
    {
        "first", "second", "third"
    };

    f( word, M );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
There are 3 non-empty strings
```

The function `f` is correct because the array word was initialized.

Comment: Thanks! the strcpy command works for me now! in the case of 
**while(*(word+count) != '\0')
{
    count ++;
    printf(" element is present");  // it is stuck in a infinite loop here. 
}**
how do you suggest i use this method to look for the end of the loop? 
With the pointer, it a string ends with \0, hence i use that for this portion too. @vlad